# Python pandas dataframe: Find last occurrence of value less-than-or-equal-to current row

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 pandas dataframes:

df1:

```
   ksat  muacres  SAND  SILT  CLAY
     0     5326     0     0     0
   0.1     4346     0     0     0
   0.4     4146     0     0     0
   0.8     3476     0     0     0
   1.2     2006     0     0     0
```

and,
df2:

```
   PERCENTILE      ksat      b  theta
0           1  0.370684  11.55   46.8
1           2  0.558053  11.55   46.8
2           3  0.794836  10.39   46.8
3           4  0.962329  11.55   46.8
4           5  1.202368  10.39   46.8
```

I want to add a column, 'st' to df1, where for each row in df1, I find the ksat value in df2, which is greater than or equal to ksat value in df1. For this example, the result would be:

df1:

```
   ksat  muacres  SAND  SILT  CLAY  st
     0     5326     0     0     0     1
   0.1     4346     0     0     0     1
   0.4     4146     0     0     0     2
   0.8     3476     0     0     0     4
   1.2     2006     0     0     0     5
```

Currently, I am looping within a loop, but that is very inefficient. Any better ways in pandas?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to merge twice. First with just the percentile column so you can backwards fill:

```
In [11]: merged = df1[['ksat']].merge(df2[['ksat', 'PERCENTILE']], how='outer', sort=True)

In [12]: merged
Out[12]:
       ksat  PERCENTILE
0  0.000000         NaN
1  0.100000         NaN
2  0.370684           1
3  0.400000         NaN
4  0.558053           2
5  0.794836           3
6  0.800000         NaN
7  0.962329           4
8  1.200000         NaN
9  1.202368           5

In [13]: merged.bfill()
Out[13]:
       ksat  PERCENTILE
0  0.000000           1
1  0.100000           1
2  0.370684           1
3  0.400000           2
4  0.558053           2
5  0.794836           3
6  0.800000           4
7  0.962329           4
8  1.200000           5
9  1.202368           5
```

and then merge with this result:

```
In [14]: df.merge(merged.bfill())
Out[14]:
   ksat  muacres  SAND  SILT  CLAY  PERCENTILE
0   0.0     5326     0     0     0           1
1   0.1     4346     0     0     0           1
2   0.4     4146     0     0     0           2
3   0.8     3476     0     0     0           4
4   1.2     2006     0     0     0           5
```

Comment: @user308827 um, what version of pandas as you using?

Comment: I think it is the latest (0.13?)

Comment: So using fillna(method=bfill) works. However, it is very slow for a df1 size of ~80,000 rows and df2 size of 100 rows. Any ideas on if the slow speed is expected would be very helpful. thanks!

Comment: @user308827 I guess it could be slow as it has to sort, shouldn't be too bad though... perhaps behzad's answer is faster when there are fewer rows in df2.

Comment: @user308827 well something is fishy as you should have a bfill method... you can check with pd.version.version.

Comment: my bad, i was using 0.9 version of pandas, upgraded through easy_install.

Answer (score 2):

you can try [`numpy.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html)

```
df1['st'] = np.searchsorted(df2.ksat, df1.ksat, side='left') + 1
```

if the `PERCENTILE` values are not ordinal then there is an extra step:

```
idx = np.searchsorted(df2.ksat, df1.ksat, side='left')
df1['st'] = df2.PERCENTILE[idx].values
```