# Divide a dataframe based on the last occurrence of a condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Let's say I have this data ordered by `id`:

```
 id | count 
 1    1
 2    2
 3    0
 4    4
 5    3
 6    2
 7    0
 8    10
 9    1
 10   2
```

I want to obtain always the last change that comes after the **last** `zero` of any. Based on the data above, I would want to get :

```
 id | count 
 8    10
 9    1
 10   2
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22322731/2988730

Comment: @MadPhysicist seems like a different situation? let me see. thanks!

Comment: It is, but it's relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`pandas`**

```
df.loc[df['count'].ne(0).iloc[::-1].cumprod().astype(bool)]

   id  count
7   8     10
8   9      1
9  10      2
```

**`numpy`**

```
df[(df['count'].values[::-1] != 0).cumprod()[::-1].astype(bool)]

   id  count
7   8     10
8   9      1
9  10      2
```

---

**with other conditions**

```
df[(df['count'].values[::-1] < 3).cumprod()[::-1].astype(bool)]
# df.loc[df['count'].lt(3).iloc[::-1].cumprod().astype(bool)]

   id  count
8   9      1
9  10      2
```

---

**debugging**
You should be able to copy and paste this and reproduce my results.  If you can't then there is something else wrong.  Try resetting your kernel.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'count': [1, 2, 0, 4, 3, 2, 0, 10, 1, 2],
        'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    })

df[(df['count'].values[::-1] < 3).cumprod()[::-1].astype(bool)]
```

---

Should produce

```
   count  id
8      1   9
9      2  10
```

Comment: Nice... nice... +1

Comment: thanks for the answer. would it be possible to provide a condition, e.g., if bigger than 3 instead of checking if equal to 0?

Comment: @renakre IIUC... yes.  Should work the same way.  `df[(df['count'].values[::-1] >= 3).cumprod()[::-1].astype(bool)]`

Comment: thanks! one `]` is missing in the second code, should it go just before `.cumprod()` ?

Comment: @renakre all three code samples I have posted in the answer work as is.

Comment: sir, for some reason this is always returning empty dataframe, did you have a chance to test it? do you see any issues with the code?

Comment: @renakre see my updated post.  I tested all variations of code I posted.  They all work as intended.  There might be a `dtype` issue or something else.  Try to copy and paste the code I provided.

Comment: thanks for checking! I just tried it, it will return a null dataset when I replace `<` with `>`. My goal is to split with any value greater than 1. thanks again!